# How to take a values from excel matching specific condition and assign it to an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel in following format

```
Category     Name                 Title
Map          Map1                 Title Automaition Map1
Topic        Topic1               Title Automaition Topic1
Topic        Topic2               Title Automaition Topic2
Submap       Submap1              Title Automaition Submap1
Sub Topic    SubTop1              Title Automaition SubTopic1
```

I want to take the values from Title column for all the Categories as Topic and store in an array. I have written the following code for taking the values from Title column for Categories as Topic

```
public class DitaExcel {

    @Test
    public void Test() throws IOException {
    {
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C://DitaExchange.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:


                            if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equalsIgnoreCase("Topic"))
                            {
                                System.out.println(row.getCell(2));

                                break;
                            }
                        break;



                    }}}}}}
```

I am getting the value as 
Title Automaition Topic1
Title Automaition Topic2

But I want to capture these values inside an array. How can I capture these values inside an array. I am expecting my output to be like this

{Title Automaition Topic1, Title Automaition Topic2}

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this...

```
    List list = new ArrayList();

code..
....
...



    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equalsIgnoreCase("Topic"))
     {
         list.add(row.getCell(2));

         break;
     }

...
...

    System.out.print("\t" + list);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to save the value in an array with your code.